# Can't compile module containing maps

Tags: erlang

I'm learning Erlang through this tutorial [maps in erlang](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/seq_prog.html#id57673)

I can't compile the maps example:

```
-module(color).

-export([new/4, blend/2]).

-define(is_channel(V), (is_float(V) andalso V >= 0.0 andalso V =< 1.0)).

new(R,G,B,A) when ?is_channel(R), ?is_channel(G),
                  ?is_channel(B), ?is_channel(A) ->
    #{red => R, green => G, blue => B, alpha => A}.

blend(Src,Dst) ->
    blend(Src,Dst,alpha(Src,Dst)).

blend(Src,Dst,Alpha) when Alpha > 0.0 ->
    Dst#{
        red   := red(Src,Dst) / Alpha,
        green := green(Src,Dst) / Alpha,
        blue  := blue(Src,Dst) / Alpha,
        alpha := Alpha
    };
blend(_,Dst,_) ->
    Dst#{
        red   := 0.0,
        green := 0.0,
        blue  := 0.0,
        alpha := 0.0
    }.

alpha(#{alpha := SA}, #{alpha := DA}) ->
    SA + DA*(1.0 - SA).

red(#{red := SV, alpha := SA}, #{red := DV, alpha := DA}) ->
    SV*SA + DV*DA*(1.0 - SA).
green(#{green := SV, alpha := SA}, #{green := DV, alpha := DA}) ->
    SV*SA + DV*DA*(1.0 - SA).
blue(#{blue := SV, alpha := SA}, #{blue := DV, alpha := DA}) ->
    SV*SA + DV*DA*(1.0 - SA).
```

My env. is:

```
-Ubuntu 14.04
-Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4)
```

Execution results:

```
1> c(color).
color.erl:9: syntax error before: '{'
color.erl:15: syntax error before: '{'
color.erl:29: syntax error before: '{'
color.erl:32: syntax error before: '{'
color.erl:34: syntax error before: '{'
color.erl:36: syntax error before: '{'
color.erl:3: function new/4 undefined
color.erl:12: function alpha/2 undefined
color.erl:12: function blend/3 undefined
error
```

A read that it could be the file encoding, so I used us-ascii, utf-8, utf-8-unix with the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement `#{red => R, ...}` is creating a Map, which is a recently-added Erlang type.

Maps were introduced in [Erlang/OTP 17](http://www.erlang.org/news/67).  You need to upgrade your VM to use them.

You could either [use package](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp) for Ubuntu, or [kerl](https://github.com/yrashk/kerl) for local/temporary installation and management for multiple Erlang versions.

Comment: [Plus one] to kerl. It makes selecting a specific version of Erlang pretty painless.